# React docx preview file with react-to-print problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, printing, docx

I am using `docx-preview` for Word files (doc,docx) preview on `React`. And user can print it. For printing I am using `react-to-print`. The problem is there. Some pages are cutting for not real font size (I think)

For example

My doc page

[image]

My `docx-preview` on react

[image]

after clicking the print

[image]

My react codes

```
import { useEffect, useRef , useState } from 'react';
import { useReactToPrint } from 'react-to-print';
import axiosInstance from 'api/axios';
import { download_File } from 'api/file';
import * as docx from 'docx-preview';

import Loading from 'components/loading/loading';

const WordPreview = ({ file, setFilePreviewModal }) => {
  const componentRef = useRef();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current.querySelector('.doc-file-wrapper'),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (file) {
      setLoading(true);
      axiosInstance({
        method: 'get',
        url: `/files/download`,
        params: {
          filePath: file?.path,
        },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      })
        .then((res) => {
          docx
            .renderAsync(res.data, document.getElementById('panel-section'), null, {
              className: 'doc-file',
              ignoreLastRenderedPageBreak: false,
            })
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));
        })
        .catch(() => {
          setFilePreviewModal(false);
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
  }, [file]);

  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? (
        <Loading />
      ) : (
        <div>
          <button onClick={handlePrint}>PRINT</button>
        </div>
      )}
      <div id="panel-section" ref={componentRef} style={{ height: '80vh' }}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WordPreview;
```

My scss

```
.file-preview-modal {
  .doc-file-wrapper {
    padding: 0 !important;
    section {
      width: 210mm !important;
      height: 290mm !important;
      min-height: 290mm !important;
      padding: 55pt !important;
      page-break-after: always;
      @page {
        size: A4;
      }
    }
  }
}

@media print {
  .doc-file-wrapper {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    section {
      width: 210mm !important;
      height: 290mm !important;
      min-height: 290mm !important;
      box-shadow: none !important;
      margin-bottom: 0px !important;
      @page {
        size: A4;
      }
    }
  }
}
```